# Couldn't connect to node because cross-origin request is blocked

Tags: web3js, cors

I am running a full rinkeby node via

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=2048  --unlock="..." --password ... --rpccorsdomain "*" --allow-insecure-unlock --rpcaddr "localhost"
```

The node is up and I could deploy a smart contract via `truffle migrate --rinkeby` and the config

```
rinkeby: {
      host: "localhost", // Connect to geth on the specified
      port: 8545,
      from: "...", // default address to use for any transaction Truffle makes during migrations
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 4612388 // Gas limit used for deploys
    }
```

My DApp is supposed to connect to the blockchain:

```
var web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
var web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);
var startBlock = web3.eth.blockNumber;
```

I get the following error (Firefox, similar for Chromium):

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8545/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8545.
```

My DApp runs on an nginx webserver (nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)).

My geth version is `1.8.27`.

Any ideas on what else I could try?

Comment: try to start geth with --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 and in the config file use  host: 
"127.0.0.1". if the problem persists what about 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

In your case CORS configuration should be set on the Geth node and not on the nginx server that serves your DApp.

You can play on the `--rpccorsdomain` configuration flag when starting your Geth node.

e.g `geth [OPTS...] --rpccorsdomain "<dapp-domain>"`

where `<dapp-domain>` is the domain your dapp is exposed on by nginx.

Comment: I played with different options for `rpccorsdomain`. In particular, I tried `--rpccorsdomain "*"`, which should be the most open. Still, I get the same error.